# How to set app background from phone gallery

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, gallery

I'm sure there is an answer out there somewhere but I can't seem to find anything.
I am trying to make it so when the user clicks on an item on the app menu it will start an intent to the phone's gallery to choose an image of their choice to change the background of the app rather than the pre-set background image. Is there a way of doing this.

Here is what code I have but when I run it on my phone, the app crashes.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    Intent sendIntent = null;
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {


        sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Try Out this new app...");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }


    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities =                   packageManager.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
    boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;


    String title = getResources().getString(R.string.chooser_title);

    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, title);


    if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(chooser);
    }



    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

    if (id == R.id.change_background){
    Intent pictureIntent = new Intent();
    pictureIntent.setType("image/*");
    pictureIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pictureIntent,
```

"Select Picture"), 0);

```
}

    return true;
```

}}

Answer (score 0):

To select the image from gallery

```
try {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),  PICK_IMAGE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }
```

and in OnActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {
    case PICK_IMAGE:

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                // OI FILE Manager
                String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                // MEDIA GALLERY
                String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                    filePath = selectedImagePath;
                } else if (filemanagerstring != null) {
                    filePath = filemanagerstring;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown path",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                if (filePath != null) {         

                    decodeFile(filePath);
                } else {
                    bitmap = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internal  
                     error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
        break;
    default:
    }



}


     //Decode file() where you will get decoded file and then you can use that image
      //file according to your requirement

   public void decodeFile(String filePath) {

    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;  
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);// set ImageView in your case set Layout  
              //background

}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I don't have onActivityResult, so when I try to copy your code I get a bunch of errors?

Comment: @DeclanMorgan cretae that method and dont just copy code..try to debug it and change it as per your requiremnents

Answer (score 0):

Try This.
this is not best way to do it. But it fulfils your need.

**xml File**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Click Me" />
```

**Java FIle**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
String path = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butt);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Icon"),
                    RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
        }
    });
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int arg0, int arg1, Intent arg2) {
    super.onActivityResult(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    try {

        if (arg0 == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && arg1 == RESULT_OK && null != arg2) {
            Uri selectedImage = arg2.getData();
            path = getPath(selectedImage);

            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
            iv.setImageURI(selectedImage);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "You haven't picked Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```